# How do lay people develop psychological theories about themselves and the world?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

**Are there models that attempt to chart how lay people develop psychological theories about themselves and their interactions with the world?**

For what it's worth, every time I read a post about emotions (or something psychological) on places like reddit, I often see so much strange logic and conceptual confusion. Their lay theories are incoherent and skew so far from scientific data/theory.  So how exactly do naive humans go about developing these theories? Do they perform some sort of hypothesis testing? Bayesian inference? How do they derive (and update) theory from the data?

Comment: Is it possible to be more domain specific?

Comment: @U.Vakil  Good question.  I'm open to an answer about any particular domain, as I'm not really sure what kind of research has examined this (so I don't want to be too limiting).  But if it's possible to use a specific domain as an example, and then extract some potentially generalizable ideas, that would be great.

Comment: Lay Theories: Everyday Understanding of Problems in the Social Sciences
(edited by Michael Argyle). Pages 151-153. You asked a question earlier about Kahneman and Tversky's work, that means you're already on the right track.

Comment: try the search terms "folk psychology"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too broad and OP hasn't responded to suggestions of the community in this respect

Comment: @Christiaan  Well, FWIW, from the comments I was able to find a book that addressed development of lay psychological theory.  But if the question stands as too broad and unanswerable, we can close it.

Comment: Could you answer the question yourself perhaps? That would be great. Happy to retract that vote and upvote your answer

Comment: Related: [What is it called when you imagine what other people would say or do in a certain situation?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/23323/7001)